# Nginx RTMP module on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nginx, rtmp

Installing Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04 was easy peasy, adding the RTMP module has resulted in less success for me. Preferably up-to-date version.
I have been using the Nginx RTMP on Previous Ubuntu versions with no problem.

I consider myself a beginner to Linux, learning on the go!
Usage: Custom mobile streaming.

Comment: How did you attempt to add the RTMP module?  Installing `libnginx-mod-rtmp`, or attempting to put a dynamic-module separately-compiled version of the module into your existing NGINX environment?

Answer (score 14):

nginx-rtmp module can be installed directly from the Ubuntu 18.04 repository

> sudo apt install libnginx-mod-rtmp

The latest version of nginx supports dynamic modules, make sure the statement to load the module is added in the nginx.conf:

> load_module "modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so";

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554405/how-to-enable-dynamic-module-with-an-existing-nginx-installation

Comment: This worked for me as well. Updated repos, installed nginx with `sudo apt install nginx`, then installed libnginx-mod-rtmp. The module was automatically picked up and loaded in nginx.conf, and nginx restarted after install :)

Answer (score 9):

You cannot install the 'latest' RTMP module without recompiling NGINX at the same time, currently.

However, the RTMP module is available in the repositories already, but it is not called in by any specific NGINX flavor anymore.  You will need to install the module with `libnginx-mod-rtmp` - this will install the RTMP module that was compiled alongside NGINX when the packages were built, and then you should just need to restart and configure NGINX to use the RTMP module and its settings.  (beyond the scope of this question)

```
sudo apt install libnginx-mod-rtmp
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

The three aforementioned commands will be able to install the RTMP module.  While it might not be the absolute *latest* of the code, it should provide most of the features that the RTMP module supports.

Comment: There are 4 nginx packages: common, light, full, and extras. Common doesn't even install the actual daemon. ALL of the other 3 give me the same error: `nginx: [emerg] "rtmp" directive is not allowed here`. Seems to be a bug in the packaging or versions somewhere. It's like it's not loading the rtmp module, but I also can't seem to find an nginx-related command to check which modules are _actually_ loaded by the runtime.

Comment: @DavidKrider `nginx-common` doesn't contain binaries because of the large number of *non-dynamic* modules that vary between the different flavors.  You must install `light`, `full`, or `extras` to get the daemon, or `core` if you're using the Ubuntu versions of the package.  You can get the list of modules available by checking `nginx -V` and checking `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled` for what dynamic modules are enabled.  (FYI I'm the maintainer of the NGINX package in Ubuntu, if you have concerns about how things're packaged direct your concerns to me directly or open a bug against nginx)

Comment: @DavidKrider *further*, `nginx-common` contains data that is common across *all* the flavors available in the repositories - basically, configuration files, etc. that're common to all the variants of nginx 'flavors'

Comment: I understand the packaging, even though it surprised me that common didn't install the daemon. The problem is that even though I install the "extras" package, and the rtmp module, and I can see the rtmp module in the list when doing `nginx -V`, I still get the error above, as if the server doesn't understand the "rtmp" directive in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

after add the rtmp module

```
 sudo apt install libnginx-mod-rtmp
```

for restarting nginx as service you can try

```
 sudo service nginx restart
```